# Optimizing a shader (OSL GLSL2.0)

Tags: android, optimization, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader

My objective is to recreate a implementation of a bubble chart in openGl so that it becomes faster. For reference, the current implementation runs at 8 fps using canvas. It draw 5200 circles in the screen on a android phone.
They change color, size, and position in real time.

I have tried to sprite batch them, but i, for some unknown reason, can't batch more than 15 at once.
Then i tried to put them all into textured rectangles, but building the mesh takes ages, and even if i don't change it between draws, it's slow.

Right now, i assume that it's possible to optimize a lot my current shaders, but i lack way too much knowledge to do so.

One potential place to optimize would be the mesh generation, currently it is like this:
x, y, z, r, g, b, a, tx, ty, x, y, z, ....
where (x, y, z) are the vertex position, (r, g, b, a) is the color and (tx, ty) are texture coordinates, however (z, r, g, b, a) are equal on all vertices of the same square. (tx, ty) are always 0,0 for vertex 1; 1, 0 for vertex 2 and so on...

Also, each square have 6 vertices instead of 4, since the same mesh have disjunct squares

My Vertex Shader:

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 aPosition;
attribute vec4 aColor;
attribute vec4 aTexCoordinate;
varying vec2 vTexCoordinate;
varying vec4 vColor;
void main() {
  vColor = aColor;
  vTexCoordinate = aTexCoordinate.xy;
  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;
}
```

My Fragment Shader:

```
private final String FragmentShaderCode = 
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoordinate;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, vTexCoordinate) *vColor;
}
```

I don't really understand how the shader code is translated into 'draw this color here', so i can't really imagine how am i supposed to solve those redundancy problems.

Edit/update:

[profiler screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QttiQ.png)

Turns out that there are two (unrelated?) methods causing the slow down. EGLImpl.eglSwapBuffers and GLES20.glClear. However, these methods don't cause slow downs if i don't draw the 5200 squares. According to [this post](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1563) it is caused by the shader (it does not happen if i don't draw the 5200 triangles), unfortunately, the poster forgot to tell what was the shader doing that caused these methods to become slow.

Update 2, the draw code, not sure if it will help though

```
public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    if (!isPacked) {
        pack();
    }
    GLES20.glUseProgram(GlProgram);
    // ////////////////////
    int mTextureUniformHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(GlProgram, "u_Texture");
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);
    // ///////////////////////
    VertexBuffer.position(0);
    int PositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(GlProgram, "aPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(PositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(PositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, (3 + 4 + 2) * 4, VertexBuffer);
    // ///////////////
    VertexBuffer.position(3);
    int ColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(GlProgram, "aColor");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(ColorHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(ColorHandle, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, (3 + 4 + 2) * 4, VertexBuffer);
    // /////////////////
    VertexBuffer.position(7);
    int TexCoordinate = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(GlProgram, "aTexCoordinate");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(TexCoordinate);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(TexCoordinate, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, (3 + 4 + 2) * 4, VertexBuffer);
    // /////////////////
    int MVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(GlProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    // /////////////
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, totalvertz);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(PositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(ColorHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(TexCoordinate);
}
```

Comment: In your fragment shader, `sampler2D` has a default precision of `lowp` and you are multiplying it by a `mediump` `vec4` (vColor). This requires the sampled texture to be converted to `mediump`, you might be able to squeeze some extra performance out of this if you use `lowp` for vColor. Probably not a lot though.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing 5200 quads is no task, it should run smoothly on any device if implemented correctly.

Your shader is too simple to be optimized, there is virtually nothing you can do here.

Before going on, have you checked for OpenGL errors? (is `glGetError() == 0`?) These can cause massive framerate drops.

EDIT:
There are a few other things I could think of, but it's hard without seeing your code:

- Are you using the FloatBuffers efficiently?
- Are you making sure not to create a new vertex buffer every frame?
- All the quads should be in one mesh, this means one draw call. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, i was checking for errors every cycle, unfortunately, it is not either a error nor the act of checking for errors that is causing the slow down

Comment: But maybe answer this in a new question. The answer to this question would be "There is no optimization possible"

Comment: Well, one of the problems i am having is not using the FloatBuffer efficiently(too much redundant information), and that would require changes in the shader, but indeed the tittle is a bit confusing.

As for the other questions, i am stil not changing the contents on the buffer between draw calls, but i will need to do later, and all triangles are in the same mesh

Comment: You should be using vertex buffer objects. You're copying the vertex buffer to the graphics chip every frame and the data isn't interleaved. Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html at *Use Vertex Buffer Objects to Manage Copying Vertex Data* about halfway down the page. Your code is like Example 9-1